# How to reject keystrokes in Python except one

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I build a terminal app in Python 3. At one point I want the program to start something and wait until the user presses Space.

I tried the following:

```
import keyboard

a = input('Write something: ')
print('Press Space to continue!')
keyboard.wait('space')
print(a)
```

That generally works as intented, but if the user presses keys other than space after the input-process, the program seems to memorize that keystrokes and after the program terminates (user presses Space finaly), the terminal executes the keystrokes that were made before Space was pressed.

How can I avoid this?

Non-Windows-exclusive prefered.

Comment: you can use msvcrt module while(msvcrt.getwche() != ' ') : continue . You might want to print a '\n' afterward.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is MS only? Correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly here you can import msvcrt as ms if you want yes

Comment: I wanted to say that I prefer a solution that works on Windows and Linux machines.